# Animating individual lines of an equation array in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, equations, equation-editor

I want to reveal one line in an equation array (generated using the "\eqarray" command in PowerPoint) at a time. I.e., I want to mimic adding a "\pause" at the end of each line break in an equation array in Beamer. How do I do this?

PowerPoint seems to treat the entire array as a single object, and not allow per-line animations.

Comment: Note that it's possible to achieve what I want simply by duplicating content across slides, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could make each line a separate equation, and so control each one separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that misses the point of using an equation array instead of separate equations to begin with. Using separate equations messes up both the alignment and the spacing between equations.